# Restrict timer of a schedule?

Tags: java, timer, schedule

Based on: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

How can I restrict a schedule that I want to run every minute, but only for working hours, let's say 8am - 4pm. `@Schedule(minute="*", hour="*")` would run continuously. How can I set start and end time?

Answer (score 0):

From your link, try `@Schedule(minute="*", hour="8-16")`